Solving the integral $\int \sqrt{\frac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}} \, dx$
I got an answer but I hardly believe that it's correct, here is what I've done so far:

i defined $u$ = $\sqrt{\frac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}}$ therefore $u^2 = {\frac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}}$
Next I isolated $e^x$ by multiplying $u^2$ with the denominator and therefore eliminating the fraction:
$u^2 * (1-e^x) = (1+e^x)$.
Then I isolated $e^x$ like this: $e^x=\frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}$ then I defined $\frac{de^x}{du} = \frac{d}{du} (\frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1})$ after applying the quotient rule i got: $\frac{4u}{(1+u^2)^2}$ and by the fact that $dx=\frac{du}{\frac{de^x}{du}}$ I found out that $dx = \frac{(1+u^2)^2}{4u} du$


After puttin everything into the previous integral (u & dx) I had:
$\int\sqrt\frac{1+e^x}{1-e^x}dx = \int u * \frac{1+u^2}{4u}du = \int {1+u^2} du = \frac{1}{4}\int1+2u^2+u^4 = \frac{1}{4}(\int1du + \int2u^2du+\int u^4du$

which then results in: $\frac{1}{4}(u+\frac{2u^3}{3}+\frac{u^5}{5}) $ after putting $u$ = $\sqrt{\frac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}}$ we get:
$\int\sqrt\frac{1+e^x}{1-e^x}dx = \frac{1}{4}(\sqrt\frac{1+e^x}{1-e^x}+\frac{2}{3}(\sqrt\frac{e^x+1}{1-e^x})^3+\frac{1}{5}(\sqrt\frac{e^x+1}{1-e^x})^5$
What do you think, is it correct? In my opinion the answer is not fitting with the others I had on the exercise sheet, but you never know. Would appreciate some tipps.
It's pretty similiar to the following question: Need help with integrating $\int \sqrt\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\, \mathrm{d}x$ But since in this exercise it's the other way around and it's not $e^x-1$ but $1-e^x$ I thought I ask again nevertheless.

In the second step, $\text dx = \text du ÷ \frac{\text d}{\text du}\left[e^x\right]$ is incorrect. Instead, you should — after isolating $e^x$ — do as follows:
$$\dfrac{\text d}{\text du}\left[e^x\right] \equiv \dfrac{\text d}{\text dx}\left[e^x\right]\cdot\dfrac{\text dx}{\text du} \equiv e^x\cdot\dfrac{\text dx}{\text du}$$

There are a lot of typos, please try to correct

There are a lot of errors in your approach! You wish to evaluate:
$$I = \int\sqrt{\dfrac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}}\text dx$$
using the substitution:
$$u^2 = \dfrac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}$$
By isolating $e^x$ and then applying implicit differentiation w.r.t. $u$, you should get that:
$$\text dx = \dfrac{4u}{\left(u^2 + 1\right)\left(u^2 - 1\right)}\ \text du$$
As a result, the integral is now:
$$I = 2\int\dfrac{2u^2}{\left(u^2 + 1\right)\left(u^2 - 1\right)}\ \text du$$
Observe that numerator can be rewritten as $2u^2 \equiv \left(u^2 + 1\right) + \left(u^2 - 1\right)$. Hence:
$$I = 2\left(\int\dfrac{1}{u^2 - 1}\ \text du + \int\dfrac{1}{u^2 + 1}\ \text du\right)$$
The integral on the right is a standard one that you should recognize if you know your derivatives well enough, while the integral on the left can be dealt with partial fractions just like how we rewrote $2u^2$ above.

I don't really understand how you got dx = $\frac{4u}{(u^2+1)(u^2-1)}$

@AsmirKalabic upon isolating $e^x$, you got that:
$$e^x = \dfrac{u^2 - 1}{u^2 + 1}$$
Now, we differentiate both sides w.r.t. $u$, as in:
$$\dfrac{\text d}{\text du}\left[e^x\right] = \dfrac{\text d}{\text du}\left[\dfrac{u^2 - 1}{u^2 + 1}\right]$$
The RHS simplifies via the quotient rule as:
$$\dfrac{4u}{\left(u^2 + 1\right)^2}$$
while the LHS can be rewritten via implicit differentiation (reminiscent to the chain rule) as:
$$\dfrac{\text d}{\text dx}\left[e^x\right]\cdot\dfrac{\text dx}{\text du} = e^x\cdot\dfrac{\text dx}{\text du}$$

Thus, replacing $e^x$ with the expression in terms of $u$ yields:
$$e^x\cdot\dfrac{\text dx}{\text du} = \dfrac{4u}{\left(u^2 + 1\right)^2}$$
$$\text dx = \dfrac{4u}{\left(u^2 + 1\right)^2}\cdot\dfrac{u^2 + 1}{u^2 - 1}\ \text du \equiv \dfrac{4u}{\left(u^2 + 1\right)\left(u^2 - 1\right)}\ \text du$$

Let's get rid of the exponential terms by enforcing the substitution  $x=\log(t)$.  Then, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{\frac{1+e^x}{1-e^x}}\,dx&=\int \sqrt{\frac{1+t}{1-t}}\frac1t\,dt
\end{align}$$
Next, we let $t=\cos(u)$ so that
$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{\frac{1+e^x}{1-e^x}}\,dx&=-\int \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(u)}{1-\cos(u)}}\tan(u)\,du\\\\
&=-\int \cot(u/2)\tan(u)\,du\\\\
&=-2\int \frac{1}{1-\tan^2(u/2)}\,du\\\\
&=2\log\left(\frac{\cos(u/2)-\sin(u/2)}{\cos(u/2)+\sin(u/2)}\right)-u+C  \\\\
&=2\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-\sqrt{1-t}}{\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1-t}}\right)-\arccos(t)+C\\\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+e^x}-\sqrt{1-e^x}}{\sqrt{1+e^x}+\sqrt{1-e^x}}\right)-\arccos(e^x)+C
\end{align}$$

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}} \, dx
=\int\frac{1+e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}} \, dx
=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}} \, dx+\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}} \, dx.$$
$$\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\, dx=\arcsin(e^x).$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\, dx=\int\frac{e^{-x}dx}{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}
=-\int\frac{d(e^{-x})}{\sqrt{(e^{-x})^2-1}}
=-\ln|e^{-x}+\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}|.$$

You forgot the $\text dx$ in the second line, but nevertheless, smart approach I must say!

@
Joyneel Bepari Thank you for pointing out!

According to Mark Viola's answer, I want to solve it in short steps.
Let $$I=\int\sqrt{\frac{1+e^{x}}{1-e^{x}}}dx$$
Now I will substitute $x=\ln(\cos(2y))$
$\implies dx=\frac{-2\sin(2y)}{\cos(2y)}dy$
$\implies dx=-2\tan(2y)dy$
Therefore the integral will be becoming $$I=-2\int\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2y)}{1-\cos(2y)}}\tan(2y)dy$$
$$\implies I=-2\int\sqrt{\frac{\cos^{2}(y)}{\sin^{2}(y)}}\tan(2y)dy$$
$$\implies I=-2\int\cot(y)\tan(2y)dy$$
Now $\cot(y)\tan(2y)=\frac{\cos(y)\sin(2y)}{\sin(y)\cos(2y)}$
$$\implies I=-2\int\frac{2\cos^{2}(y)}{\cos(2y)}dy$$
Now $2\cos^{2}(y)=(1+\cos(2y))$
$$\implies I=-2\int\frac{1+\cos(2y)}{\cos(2y)}dy$$
Now integrate separately.
Note: $\int\sec(x)dx=\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|+C$
This is a bit short process.
